# Function definition without compound statement in C

Tags: c

I am confused by the following function definition without a compound statement in C:

```
void
__tu_finishme(const char *file, int line, const char *format, ...)
   tu_printflike(3, 4);
```

It seems to not result in a function in generated object files, while the linker still expects `__tu_finishme` to have been written.
Especially odd to me since

```
void
__tu_finishme(const char *file, int line, const char *format, ...) {
   tu_printflike(3, 4);
}
```

seems to have different (AKA "normal") linkage than the former.

Can someone please explain which concept and niche of the C language I encounter here and how it works?

Bonus points for explaining things like:

```
void
foo(const char* c)
   bar()
{
    ha = hoo();
    boo(ha);
}
```

Comment: `tu_printflike(3, 4)` is a macro which expands to something like `__attribute__((__format__(__printf__, 3, 4)))`. It's not the body of the function, it's an indication for the compiler to make some checks. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)

Answer (score 3):

`tu_printflike` is very likely a *macro* that expands to an [attribute like](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-format-function-attribute):

```
__attribute__ ((format (printf, 3, 4)))
```

The above is GCC specific, so the use of a macro is there to enable portability across compilers, it can be defined as something akin to

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  define tu_printflike(i, j) __attribute__ ((format (printf, i, j)))
#else
#  define tu_printflike(i, j) 
#endif
```

Your bonus point can be explained just the same with

```
#define bar()
```

Where the definition is just an empty token sequence, the function like macro expands to nothing.

Comment: Thanks. Changed `tu_printflike` now to `TU_PRINTFLIKE` and now my feeble little mind can work with that ;)